# how concatenate 2 values lookup.addLookupfield Dynamics ax

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

I have no idea how to concatenate 2 values on the same field , I mean something like this:

```
lookup.addLookupfield(fieldNum(Table, ProductName)," " ,fieldNum(Table,ProductPrice));
```

This is my code for now:

```
lookup.addLookupfield(fieldNum(BBP_TableProducts, ProductName));
```

Comment: If your talking about string concatenation, then you can just use the `+` operator.

Comment: What is `lookup`? What kind of argument(s) does `addLookupField` take? What does `fieldNum` return?

Comment: You can pass only one field id in addLookupfield. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/systablelookup.addlookupfield.aspx  So not sure what is your objective?

Comment: Its not posible do that ? @PradeepMuttikulangaraVasu mm I'm trying to show on the row of the Lookup "Beer $5.00" without colums but now I only want to change de width of the Lookup, any suggestion ?

Comment: You can add custom lookup like http://devexpp.blogspot.com/2012/02/dynamics-ax-custom-lookup.html SysTableLookup sysTableLookup = SysTableLookup::newParameters(tableNum(ProjTable), this);
    
            sysTableLookup.addLookupfield(fieldNum(ProjTable, ProjId));
            sysTableLookup.addLookupfield(fieldNum(ProjTable, DataAreaId));
            sysTableLookup.addLookupfield(fieldNum(ProjTable, Name));
            sysTableLookup.addLookupfield(fieldNum(ProjTable, Type));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have add 2 field in lookup you have to do it in *2 separate lines*.

**For example:**

```
lookup.addLookupfield(fieldNum(Table, ProductName));
lookup.addLookupfield(fieldNum(Table, ProductPrice));
```

This is the definition of `addLookupfield` function

```
public void addLookupfield(FieldId _fieldId, [boolean _returnItem])
```

You can't concatenate values in the same `addLookupfield` function.